# How to make the background darker

Tags: html, css, reactjs, dom, sass

I tried to blend the background but my foreground text and images are also getting coloured. How can I make the video part darker (only the video, without affecting outer components, as it is a React-based project)?

Code for the App component:

```
import './App.css';
import Footer from './Components/Footer';
import Header from './Components/Header';
function App() {
  // let imageArr = ["back.jpg", "front.jpg", "right.jpg"];
  // let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArr.length);
  // let randomImage = imageArr[randomNum];
  return (
    // <div className="App" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${randomImage})`}}>

    <>
      <video src="back.mp4" loop autoplay="autoplay" muted></video>
      <div className='container'>

        <div className='container'>
          <Header />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
    // </div>

  );
}
```

CSS code for the app component:

```css
.App
{
  background-size:cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width:100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  background:  no-repeat center center fixed;
  
}
.container
{
  padding: 3%;
  margin: 0px;
  
}
video
{
border: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width:  100vw;
  height:1fr;
 overflow: hidden;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the code in the

```
video {
border: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width:  100vw;
  height:1fr;
 overflow: hidden;

}
```

so only the video gets applied with the effects you want.